# Android NDK NativeActivity access GestureDetector

Tags: android, android-ndk, detection, gesture

Is it possible for the NativeActivity to access a GestureDetector and bind events to it?

I'm thinking this might have to go through the JNI, painfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must use JNIEnv to access GestureDetector - it's Java class.

All the C API are listed in `STABLE-APIS.html` file under `docs` folder.